# What documents do I need to take a German airplane outside of Schengen but still within the EU?

Tags: general-aviation, easa-regulations, eu

What kind of documents are required for customs or police if one flies out of Schengen (in this case a German-registered aircraft) and lands in a non-Schengen state within the EU?

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! Questions about customs or police (I guess you mean immigration?) should be asked on [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/). You can ask about relevant aviation regulations here.

Comment: I mean for the airplane.

Comment: OK, but then Schengen has nothing to do with it. It is only about immigration. What might be more relevant is whether or not the country you fly to is an EASA member state (as far as I know, all EU members are also EASA members).

Comment: I see, so an "airport of entry" is only about customs for people, not for "legally taking the plane" to a country?